# How to still print Java Stack trace to console when using Sentry

Tags: java, exception, logging, console, sentry

I am using Sentry to log my Java exceptions in an application I am building.

Sentry is awesome for Production issues but when I'm just messing about in development I want to be able to still get the stack trace out to the console.

However, once `Sentry.init(...)` has been run exceptions seem to be suppressed and only available on the Sentry website.

What is the option that I should set in `Sentry.init(...)` to continue having console stack traces for development?

Comment: if you call `init` it should enable it in any environment. You're saying that in development the events don't get to Sentry?

Comment: No, the events get to Sentry but uncaught exceptions no longer also go the command prompt.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. What do you mean by "also go to the command prompt? It this a console app and it crashes with an unhandled error (which you see at Sentry) but you expect the exception to be printed to the terminal? Sentry shouldn't affect that. If you remove Sentry you see something on the console but if you add Sentry you don't?

Comment: If one does not have sentry installed then uncaught errors get printed to System.err and thus displayed in the terminal. With Sentry enabled it swallows all the errors and the only way to see them is by looking in Sentry.

Comment: Sentry takes the Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler but it does forward the call to the original one. So if the original was writing to the terminal before crashing, it should still do that. Can you please raise an issue with a repro on GH? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java

Comment: Have you tried to set debut to true on the options https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/configuration/options/#debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to deal with that. Both can be configured in `Sentry.init`. I hope it is fine if share my `Kotlin` snippets, it shouldn't be very different in `Java`.

If it is okay for you to not send the uncaught exceptions to Sentry you can disable the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```kt
if (environment == "DEVELOPMENT") {
  options.enableUncaughtExceptionHandler = false
}
```

Otherwise, if you still want to have that exceptions in Sentry, you could use `setBeforeSend` to print it to the console first:

```kt
options.setBeforeSend { event, hint ->
  if (environment == "LOCAL") {
    System.err.println(event.throwable?.printStackTrace())
  }
  return@setBeforeSend event
}
```

Comment: The `System.err.println` is useless. `printStackTrace()` already prints to `System.err`. It then returns Unit, which is printed by `println` as `kotlin.Unit` after the stacktrace.